# undergrad general time complexity:comparing B-tree over black red tree

Tags: time, b-tree, processing-efficiency

I am new at data structure. I understand we use B tree to minimize disk rotation, but why we use black-red tree for memory over B-tree? Isnt that both perform at O(log n)? In my opnion B-tree has smaller height and require less space (can have t-1 to 2t-1 keys), while black-red tree must have 2 child for internal node.

Answer (score 0):

Red black B tree is a self balancing B tree. Non self balancing B trees can become inefficient, though you and process them and manually rebalance any time that means a big fat lock!

Both being binary trees, yes they are both O(log n), until the B tree becomes unbalanced over time, and then O(log n) is not guaranteed any more.

Answer (score 0):

The main cost of red-black tree boils down to a very simple problem of swapping out a single red capacity near the root to the perfect black tree top.
Assuming red node generation is uniform, the total cost sum of uniform subtree volumes is quadratic. Because the black height is basically invariant, a single red node generates global red waterfall, self-amplifying while falling up to the top.

The red capacity is linear to the black-tree volume. The extra red-absorption capacity is relative to the black tree height. Every single red capacity absorption moves up exactly one black hole. The black hole moves up step by step.

The total red capacity flow is described as a simple red heat flow to the black tree top, which is a very simple heatbath.

Comment: This fundamental quadratic swapping cost should be regareded as the natural entropy flow of any uniform binary tree algorithm. It's exactly identical to the quadratic swapping cost of a simple static sorting, hence should be considered fundamental.